# Magento 2: Not able to revert Category URL Suffix and Product URL Suffix to .html

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.7

I am having strange trouble in my Magento 2.1.7 website. As per my client's requirement, I changed category URL suffix and product URL suffix to blank.

**Issue 1:** After making such changes in the settings, I got the following error:

> Error filtering template: Element with ID 'widget.products.list.pager' already exists.

**Issue 2:** After getting above error, I tried to reindex, flush cache and deploy static content, but nothing worked. Then I tried to revert back my changes and set .html as URL suffix again.

Now the setting is being saved in the admin panel but nothing is being changed in the frontend.

I am still getting category and product URLs without .html.

Kindly suggest, how can I get rid of such problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing **var** folder and run the reindex command **php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

Or you can tryout the URL regenerate:
https://github.com/karliuka/m2.IndexerUrlRewrite

Comment: Already tried removing var folder and ran reindex, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should add .html again in the backend for Category URL Suffix and Product URL Suffix, after that need to run these commands:

1. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
2. rm -rf var/cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
3. php bin/magento cache:clean
4. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
5. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
6. php bin/magento cache:flush
7. chmod -Rf 777 var/* generated/* pub/*

and then you can see all .html will be shown in end of the urls of categories or products.